# Does XML officially support a "dir" or "xml:dir" attribute?

Tags: xml, bidi

You can find various documents that say to specify the language of the content of an XML document, use `xml:lang`, like this:

```
<foobar xml:lang="en">...</foobar>
```

HTML and XHTML has the attribute `dir` that lets you specify that the text should be considered left-to-right by default, or right-to-left by default:

```
<html dir="rtl">...</html>
```

Is there an equivalent attribute for XML? Is the only solution to include Unicode RIGHT-TO-LEFT mark in every text node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) itself does not address directionality (although it does address [language identification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-lang-tag) as you mention with `xml:lang`).

However, in the [W3C Best Practices for XML Internationalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-i18n-bp/), see [Best Practice 2: **Defining markup to specify text direction**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-i18n-bp/#DevDir) for how to use the [`its:dir`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-its-20070403/#att.dir) attribute and [`its:dirRule`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-its-20070403/#dirRule) element to specify directional markup via the [Internationalization Tag Set](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-its-20070403/).