# Issue with arabic language translation in android

Tags: android, localization, arabic

I am having string like this in my string.xml for arabic language.

```
<string name="storyboard_duration" ><xliff:g id="duration" >%1$ds</xliff:g></string>
<string name="str_date_yymmdd_format"><xliff:g id="date" >%1$d-%2$d-%3$d</xliff:g></string>
<string name="str_date_ddmmyy"><xliff:g id="date_summary" >dd-mm-yy</xliff:g></string>
```

it is still translating number in arabic rather than showing in English.

Comment: Could you specify what platform are you using? Windows, iOS, Android, etc.? And maybe you can show a screen shot.

Comment: Android platform.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere the system is getting a right-to-left signal. This could be coming from device settings. One thing you could try is to force a language and `ltr` (left-to-right) direction in the xml code through the `lang` and `dir` attributes. See this question and answer for more on this:

[Does XML officially support a "dir" or "xml:dir" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995517/does-xml-officially-support-a-dir-or-xmldir-attribute)